# Email won't show on iPhone

Tags: html, css, email

I'm fairly new to coding and designing for email, so I've read up a lot on how to avoid any problematic code. Still, I ran into problems.

I'm trying to make an email using HTML, and it works fairly well on every other platform except for iPhone. On iPhones, only some of the links show between <>'s, with seemingly all of the HTML stripped away.

The first time my colleague looked at the email using Outlook (the program itself), it also had the same problem.

Anyone have a tip for how to solve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <style>
    #knapp {
        background-color:#00A49C;
        border-radius:30px;
        color:#ffffff;
        display:inline-block;
        font-family:arial;
        font-size:15px;
        line-height:42px;
        text-align:center;
        text-decoration:none;
        width:200px;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
    }

    p {
        font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; color: #1D2242;
    }

    h1 {
        font-family: arial; font-size: 16pt; color: #1D2242;
    }

    #bakgrunn {
        background-color: #F3F1E9; width: 98%; padding: 20px;
    }

    body {
        background-color: #F3F1E9;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#F3F1E9">
    <center>
        <!-- Ytterste table -->
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="98%" style="background-color: #F3F1E9; width: 98%; padding: 20px" id="bakgrunn">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <!-- header-table -->
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 40px 0px 10px 0px;">
                                <center><a href="https://xxx.no/familie"><img src="https://unity.xxx.no/Portal/Images/xxx_logo_Grey.png" alt="xxx Familie-logo" width="150px" align="center"></a></center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <!-- Hoved-table -->
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" style="max-width: 500px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h1 style="font-family: arial; font-size: 16pt; color: #1D2242">Hovedtittel</h1>
                                <p style="font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; color: #1D2242; line-height: 1.4">
                                    Tekst</p> <p style="font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; color: #1D2242; line-height: 1.4">Last ned xxx Familie til din telefon i dag p&aring; <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/no/developer/xxx-as/id331546826?l=nb" style="color: #0080D7">iOS</a> eller <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=xxx+AS&hl=no" style="color: #0080D7">Android</a>!
                                    </br></p>

                                    <center><table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a href="https://itunes.apple.com/no/developer/xxx-as/id331546826?l=nb"><img style="height: 45px; padding:10px 5px 7px 5px" alt="Apple store" src="https://xxx.no/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/App-store-ikon.png"></a></td>
                                                <td><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=xxx+AS&hl=no"><img style="height: 45px; padding:10px 5px 7px 5px" alt="Google play" src="https://xxx.no/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Google-play-ikon.png"></a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table></center>
                                <p style="font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; color: #1D2242; line-height: 1; padding-bottom:0px; margin-bottom:-10px;">
                                    <strong>Tittel</strong>
                                </p><p style="font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; color: #1D2242; line-height: 1.4;padding-top:0px">tekst</a>.
                                    </br></p>
                                </br>
                                <!-- Button -->
                                    <center><div>
                                          <a href="http://xxx.no/familie"
                                    style="
                                    background-color:#00A49C;
                                    border-radius:30px;
                                    color:#ffffff;
                                    display:inline-block;
                                    font-family:arial;
                                    font-size:15px;
                                    line-height:42px;
                                    text-align:center;
                                    text-decoration:none;
                                    width:200px;
                                    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">Les mer</a>
                                </div></center>
                                <!-- slutt Button -->
                                </br>
                                <p style="font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; color: #1D2242; line-height: 1.4">Hilsen oss i xxx
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- Slutt Hoved-table -->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!-- Footer-table -->
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" style="padding-bottom: 30px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <center>
                                    <div style="padding:0px; margin: -5px"><p style="font-family: arial; font-size: 10pt; color: #1D2242; font-style: italic; line-height: 1">
                                    <a href="mailto:hei@xxx.no" style="color: #0080D7">hei@xxx.no</a>
                                </p></div>
                                <div style="padding:0px; margin: -5px 0px 10px 0px"><p style="font-family: arial; font-size: 10pt; color: #1D2242; font-style: italic; line-height: 1"><a href="https://xxx.no/personvernpolicy/" style="color: #0080D7">Personvern</a>
                                </p></div>
                                    <center>
                                        <a href="http://facebook.com/xxxx/"><img src="https://xxx.no/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Facebook-1.png" style="height: 20px; padding: 5px" alt="Facebook"></a>
                                        <a href="http://twitter.com/xxx"><img src="https://xxx.no/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Twitter-1.png" style="height: 20px; padding: 5px" alt="Twitter"></a>
                                        <a href="http://youtube.com/channel/UCaXOA8S5shv0XDb3Dontz4w"><img src="https://xxx.no/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/YouTube.png" style="height: 20px; padding: 5px" alt="YouTube"></a>
                                    <a href="http://linkedin.com/company/xxx-as/"><img src="https://xxx.no/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/LinkedIn.png" style="height: 20px; padding: 5px" alt="LinkedIn"></a> </center>
                                </center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- Slutt Footer-table -->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table><!-- Slutt ytterste table -->
    </center>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Stack overflow did something weird to my code. I've changed it now (none of the links will work, since my company's name have been replaced with xxx)

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code...

for example here the you don't open the a tag.

```
<td style="padding: 40px 0px 10px 0px;">
                                http://www.helenefosse.no/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/HF-logo_black.png" alt="Sensio Familie-logo" width="150px" align="center"></a></center>
                            </td>
```

You have links to emails without mailto:, etc, etc...

I would advice you to use https://validator.w3.org/ to validade your html, check the errors that come up and once all is corrected try again.

Answer (score -1):

You had some HTML errors in your code. Here I've corrected all of them.

> **EDIT:** Code updated after question edit.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <style>
    #knapp {
      background-color: #00A49C;
      border-radius: 30px;
      color: #ffffff;
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: arial;
      font-size: 15px;
      line-height: 42px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      width: 200px;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    }
    
    p {
      font-family: arial;
      font-size: 14pt;
      color: #1D2242;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-family: arial;
      font-size: 16pt;
      color: #1D2242;
    }
    
    #bakgrunn {
      background-color: #F3F1E9;
      width: 98%;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: #F3F1E9;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#F3F1E9">
  <center>
    <!-- Ytterste table -->
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="98%" style="background-color: #F3F1E9; width: 98%; padding: 20px" id="bakgrunn">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
          <!-- header-table -->
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%">
            <tr>
              <td style="padding: 40px 0px 10px 0px;">
                <center>
                  <a href="https://xxx.no/familie"><img src="https://unity.xxx.no/Portal/Images/xxx_logo_Grey.png" alt="xxx Familie-logo" width="150px" align="center"></a>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!-- Hoved-table -->
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" style="max-width: 500px">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <h1 style="font-family: arial; font-size: 16pt; color: #1D2242">Hovedtittel</h1>
                <p style="font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; color: #1D2242; line-height: 1.4">
                  Tekst</p>
                <p style="font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; color: #1D2242; line-height: 1.4">Last ned xxx Familie til din telefon i dag p&aring;
                  <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/no/developer/xxx-as/id331546826?l=nb" style="color: #0080D7">iOS</a> eller <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=xxx+AS&hl=no" style="color: #0080D7">Android</a>!
                  <br/>
                </p>

                <center>
                  <table>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/no/developer/xxx-as/id331546826?l=nb">
                            <img style="height: 45px; padding:10px 5px 7px 5px" alt="Apple store" src="https://xxx.no/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/App-store-ikon.png">
                          </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=xxx+AS&hl=no">
                            <img style="height: 45px; padding:10px 5px 7px 5px" alt="Google play" src="https://xxx.no/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Google-play-ikon.png">
                          </a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </center>
                <p style="font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; color: #1D2242; line-height: 1; padding-bottom:0px; margin-bottom:-10px;">
                  <strong>Tittel</strong>
                </p>
                <p style="font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; color: #1D2242; line-height: 1.4;padding-top:0px">
                  <a>tekst</a>.
                  <br/>
                </p>
                <br/>
                <!-- Button -->
                <center>
                  <div>
                    <a href="http://xxx.no/familie" style="
                                    background-color:#00A49C;
                                    border-radius:30px;
                                    color:#ffffff;
                                    display:inline-block;
                                    font-family:arial;
                                    font-size:15px;
                                    line-height:42px;
                                    text-align:center;
                                    text-decoration:none;
                                    width:200px;
                                    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">Les mer</a>
                  </div>
                </center>
                <!-- slutt Button -->
                <br/>
                <p style="font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; color: #1D2242; line-height: 1.4">Hilsen oss i xxx
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!-- Slutt Hoved-table -->
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!-- Footer-table -->
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" style="padding-bottom: 30px">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center>
                  <div style="padding:0px; margin: -5px">
                    <p style="font-family: arial; font-size: 10pt; color: #1D2242; font-style: italic; line-height: 1">
                      <a href="mailto:hei@xxx.no" style="color: #0080D7">hei@xxx.no</a>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div style="padding:0px; margin: -5px 0px 10px 0px">
                    <p style="font-family: arial; font-size: 10pt; color: #1D2242; font-style: italic; line-height: 1">
                      <a href="https://xxx.no/personvernpolicy/" style="color: #0080D7">Personvern</a>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <center>
                    <a href="http://facebook.com/xxxx/"><img src="https://xxx.no/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Facebook-1.png" style="height: 20px; padding: 5px" alt="Facebook"></a>
                    <a href="http://twitter.com/xxx"><img src="https://xxx.no/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Twitter-1.png" style="height: 20px; padding: 5px" alt="Twitter"></a>
                    <a href="http://youtube.com/channel/UCaXOA8S5shv0XDb3Dontz4w"><img src="https://xxx.no/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/YouTube.png" style="height: 20px; padding: 5px" alt="YouTube"></a>
                    <a href="http://linkedin.com/company/xxx-as/"><img src="https://xxx.no/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/LinkedIn.png" style="height: 20px; padding: 5px" alt="LinkedIn"></a>
                  </center>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!-- Slutt Footer-table -->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Slutt ytterste table -->
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```